# Convert widget from popular posts to recent posts?

Tags: blogger

I'm not much of a coder, so I've been using a blogger template to put together what I'm doing. There is a widget that displays popular posts, but I'd like to convert it to display the most recent posts instead. Do I have to do this through some sort of RSS tracking?

Here is the widget currently:
`<b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='true' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>`
`<b:includable id='main'>`
`<div class='widget-content popular-posts'>`
`<ul>`
`<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>`
`<div class='featured_item'>`
`<b:if cond='data:showThumbnails == &quot;false&quot;'>`
`<b:if cond='data:showSnippets == &quot;false&quot;'>`
`<!-- (1) No snippet/thumbnail -->`
`<a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a>`
`<b:else/>`
`<!-- (2) Show only snippets -->`
`<div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>`
`<div class='item-snippet'><data:post.snippet/></div>`
`</b:if>`
`<b:else/>`
`<b:if cond='data:showSnippets == &quot;false&quot;'>`
`<!-- (3) Show only thumbnails -->`
`<div class='item-thumbnail-only'>`
`<b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>`
`<div class='item-thumbnail'>`
`<a expr:href='data:post.href' target='_blank'>`
`<img alt='' border='0' expr:height='data:thumbnailSize' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' expr:width='data:thumbnailSize'/>`
`</a>`
`</div>`
`</b:if>`
`<div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></div>`
`</div>`
`<div style='clear: both;'/>`
`<b:else/>`
`<!-- (4) Show snippets and thumbnails -->`
`<div class='folderboxpic'>`
`<a class='article' expr:href='data:post.href' rel='bookmark'>`
`<b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>`
`<img expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' height='72' width='72'/>`
`<b:else/>`
`<img alt='no image' height='200' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-G9M2DTCTUwM/Tlh-2pwtc5I/AAAAAAAABKM/kCJg-Kf3W2M/s200/no_image_yet.jpg' width='200'/>`
`</b:if>`
`<div class='folderboxtitle'><div class='folderboxbackground'><div id='tm-folderboxbackground-720'><data:post.title/></div></div></div>`
`</a>`
`<div class='clear'/>`
`</div>`
`</b:if>`
`</b:if>`
`</div>`
`</b:loop>`
`</ul>`
`</div>`
`</b:includable>`
`</b:widget>`

Answer (score 2):

You cant change that widget.Instead you would have to go for another widget.The official blogger list in the layout menu does not have it.There are tons of "recent posts" widgets available with different settings and looks around the internet.Just Google "recent posts widget blogger".
Once you find the code....go to layout,add widget,add html/3rd party code and paste it,save :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the OP, I wanted to replace the default *Popular Posts* gadget with a *Recent Posts* gadget. This is because I wanted to present a navigation path to all my posts. Well, that's not a real solution because neither *Popular Posts* nor *Recent Posts* will display all posts.

Please consider Blogger's simple, native solution to this navigation problem: [display a list of all posts on the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452610/).

While *Popular Posts* is not very interesting on a new blog, We can hope that *Popular Posts* will become more interesting as the site gets more organic visitors.